# get-counter in powershell returning null

Tags: powershell-3.0, performancecounter

Using powershell v3, when running the following command to try and list all the counter sets for a local sql server express, I get a list of counter sets on my local machine correctly;

```
get-counter -listset 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS*'
```

But, when I try to see the individual paths using the following statement, I get null.

```
(get-counter -listset 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS*').paths
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following return anything?

`get-counter -listset 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS*' | Select Paths`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was running the command on my pc which is running powershell V2 not V3 as stated in my original question. 
When I run the command in PS v3, it is working fine. So it must be version related.